# Как сделать редактируемый заголовок Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Имеется сайт на 1С Битрикс. С разработкой на битрикс сталкиваюсь впервые, поэтому приношу извинения если где-то в документации к нему не нашел ответ.

Имеется вот такой header с компонентом menu и заголовком "Blog template".

Какой компонент добавить для "Blog template" чтобы его можно было менять через админку, без внедрения в код? И, возможно, добавить к нему ссылку перехода на главную страницу.
Заранее большое спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще обычно заголовок сайтов на Битриксе выводится конструкцией `<?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?>` в head'е. Чтобы его изменить, достаточно в административной панели выбрать "Изменить страницу" -> "Заголовок и свойства страницы".

Comment: <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?> это скорее для мета или h1 и более статичного контента. Ссылку в ShowTitle не прокинуть и отредактировать ее тоже не получится

Comment: @Taarim, ну, чтобы сделать ссылку, в любом случае придётся в код лезть. Надо смотреть, чем именно выводится заголовок в конкретном месте страницы, и оборачивать в `<a href="/"></a>`

Comment: А вот если там точно будет всегда текст и ссылку редактировать не нужно, то ваш вариант наиболее правильный из всех представленных

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы по нажатию на текст "Blog temlate" переходил на главную страницу, то можно сделать гиперссылку

```
href="/"
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас 3 варианта для решения проблемы:

1. самый простой, но потребует некоторого знания разметки от менеджера магазина. - завернуть нужный блок в подключаемую область. Для успешных манипуляций с разметкой внутри включаемой области не должно быть php кода типа SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH и подобных.
2. Чуть посложнее но уже для разработчика: вынести нужную ссылку в параметры подключаемой включаемой области. Копируем дефолтный шаблон компонента и в скопированном шаблоне редактируем файл .parameters.php - т.е ссылку выносим в параметры и внутри включаемой области используем $arParams['MY_PARAMETER']. И отключаем редактирование включаемой области, чтобы работали только настройки.
3. Создаем ИБ контент (название может быть любым). создаем елемент с текстом и ссылкой и выводим в шаблоне при помощи news.detail или с

Answer (score 0):

если заголовок всегда один, вставьте вместо него компонент включаемая область из файла, а в файл области пишите хоть текст хоть HTML